# How to display the value of a cookie in a .html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have this jquery: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie (jquery.cookie.js)
And this is my cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //hide all divs just for the purpose of this example, 
    //you should have the divs hidden with your css

    //$('.picture.1').hide();
    //check if the cookie is already setted
    if ($.cookie("currentDiv")===undefined){
            $.cookie("currentDiv",1);
    } else{ //else..well 
            //get and increment value, let's suppose we have just 8 divs     

            var numValue = parseInt($.cookie("currentDiv"));
            numValue = numValue + 1;
            if (numValue>8){
            //restart to 1
                $.cookie("currentDiv",1);
            }
            else{ //no issues, assign the incremented value
                $.cookie("currentDiv",numValue.toString());
            }

            //show the div
            $('.picture.'+$.cookie("currentDiv")).show(0);
    }
});
```

The cookie called currentDiv has a number from 1 to 8 and changes every reload and reset when the value is higher as 8

How can I display the cookie (called currentDiv) with his current value?
Like:

```
The installed cookies are:
   currentDiv with the value (for example 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this to list all the pages cookies:

```
<span id="myId"><span>
<script>
document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML=listCookies()
function listCookies() {
    var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var aString = '';
    for (var i = 1 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
        aString += i + ' ' + theCookies[i-1] + "\n";
}
    return aString;
}
</script>
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/5p34S/

Comment: checkmark the answer to label the question as answered,your welome

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding, create an element for the cookie value display, say its ID is "display-value".
Within the `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`, add `$("#display-value").text("The installed cookies are: currentDiv " + ($.cookie("currentDiv") || 0));` to the end (or to the beginning, depends on when you want to show it).